# Compare results from a previous test in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to run a test every 3 days and compare some of the results with the last test run. What is the best way to achieve this? I have considered writing the results to files and reading the values for comparison in the next test but having difficulty generating unique file names automatically and having the test recognise which one to use in the next test run.

Answer (score 2):

- If you are using Jenkins to run your test periodically you can use `Performance Plugin' of jenkins for JMeter to compare the results of every run.

For more details: http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-continuous-performance-testing-part2/

- You can also use Grafana to compare the results.

For more details: http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-real-time-results-influxdb-grafana/

- [Blazemeter sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) - and you need [this plugin](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/LoadosophiaUploader/) to upload the results to Blazemeter sense.