# How Can I compare output of 2 different JMeter runs automatically?

Tags: performance, jenkins, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I want to compare 2 different jmeter runs.
I have a jenkins job to do that which triggers jmx which in turn call Rest APIs.
Lets say, I executed Jmeter run for one time. I will refer this as run 1
Now, after 30 minutes, I will again run the same jenkins job and will again run the jmeter test. I will refer to it as run 2.

So, now i have 2 runs and i want to compare run1 and run2, specifically the response time.
How can I automate that so that everytime this happens, i can have the difference in response time of APIs ?

I tried searching, found few articles ([Compare results from a previous test in jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448130/compare-results-from-a-previous-test-in-jmeter)) but it did not really help :(

Please let me know how can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MergeResults](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) plugin in order to compare 2 test executions and plot execution chart and/or have differences in the CSV file.

[image: JMeter Plugins Merge Results]

If you want to run it in non-GUI mode from Jenkins job - go for [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) which has `MergeResults` plugin to run it in command-line mode.

You can install both the plugins using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)